Apple Silicon AWS Fargate ECS Error 400 while pushing AMD64 Images
I have an issue with my brand new M3 Pro :(
i have a webapp written in php and properly dockerized. docker-compose, docker-watch work like charm. however if it try to deploy the app to AWS' ECS (former Fargate) i always see this error:
.
.
d3b3296fbfd2: Pushed
58a73444ef77: Pushed
db344eee10a7: Pushed
failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:xxxxxxxxx": unexpected status from PUT request to https://xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v2/cdk-xxxxx-container-assets-xxxxxx-eu-central-1/manifests/xxxxxxxx: 400 Bad Request
phpFargate2:  fail: docker push xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cdk-xxxxx-container-assets-xxx-eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx exited with error code 1: failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx": unexpected status from PUT request to https://xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v2/cdk-xxxxx-container-assets-xxx-eu-central-1/manifests/xxxxxxxx: 400 Bad Request

i have added
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 webdevops/php-apache-dev:8.2 AS php-with-node
to my Dockerfile, and i have Rosetta enabled.
i also removed
credsStore: osxKeyChain
from .docker/docker-config.json
In Elastic Container Registry, the image size is shown as 0 bytes.
i also tried to authenticate in ECR separately with
aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-central-1 --profile xxx | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
and i get
Login Succeeded!
aws sts get-caller-identity --profile xxx
also successful
Maybe anyone of you can help me, as i'm running out of ideas.
Note: Pushing from windows doesnt show these issues. So this time it's the other way around....
Regards,
Adrian

That's one for AWS support really if their container repo is rejecting pushes from the real docker client. They have their own ARM servers so I'd be surprised if they're rejecting ARM images (although I don't know how compatible the two are)

And I'd hope they could give you more information in that case anyway, although that might be down to the to docker client after all e.g. if there was a useful response body in the 400 it's not showing you. Is there any way to see the full response from AWS there?

with FROM --platform=linux/amd64 webdevops/php-apache-dev:8.2 AS php-with-node i force the creation of x86 images

ECS has a dedicated section for ARM images called Graviton (hail to the buzzword)

Have you tried building and pushing that image to ECR from another computer, just to narrow down what the issue might be? This seems like it may be some sort of issue with the Docker install on your laptop, or possibly something wrong with the way you are building the docker images. Note that this has nothing to do with ECS or Fargate, since you aren't even getting to that point yet. ECR also doesn't care that you built the image on "apple silicon", plenty of people build images on Macs and run them on  AWS.

the same deployment runs on a windows machine without issues

I finally fixed it with the help of this post
error: failed to solve: failed commit on ref : unexpected status: 400 Bad Request
the 'trick' is basically to disable 'tag immutability' inside the ECR settings.
thanks for your help
adrian

Glad you solved it! Why would that have worked on Windows not Mac if it's an ECR setting?

that’s indeed suspect. i was lucky to make it work. but i still don’t understand why there was a difference. that would mean that windows creates a new tag each time and osx doesn’t. but i don’t believe this
